# Combining the output of classification models for different attributes

Tags: probability, classification

I have several classification models that predict various attributes of a person. For example, these models could predict sex, age, hair colour, etc. The outputs of my models are probabilities of each attribute (e.g., for a given input it might predict 0.23 male, 0.77 female). I'd like to combine these predictions into an overall prediction of a person.

My gut says I should multiply these probabilities together for each possible combination of attributes. For example, I would multiply the probabilities together for 45-55 year old and male and brown hair to get the probability that my data refer to a 45-55 year old male with brown hair.

**Question #1**: Is this an appropriate way to combine the output of several classification models?

Now, say I *also* have a model that predicts individual people directly. That is, for a given data set it predicts the likelihood that the data refer to a specific person from a group of people, such as John Smith, Sally Jones, etc.

**Question #2**: How can I combine the output from my attribute classification models together with my person classification model to get a more robust prediction?

For example, my individual person model may predict that Sally Jones – who is a 25-35 year old female with blond hair – is the most likely candidate,  but my other models say it's more likely that it is a 55-65 year old red-headed male. To combine predictions would I simply multiply together the probabilities for 25-35 year old and female and blond hair and Sally Jones to get a new probability for Sally Jones that is weighted by the output of the attribute classification models?

Comment: Q1: This relies on attributes being independent, which may or may not be OK as an approximation in your case. In general I'd be skeptical about this.

Comment: Q2: You seem to assume implicitly that the individual person prediction is in contradiction to the attribute predictors, but in fact the probability for Sally Jones from the person predictor may not be in any contradiction to the attribute predictors - surely not as long as we don't know based on what information and in which way these predictions were made. So the Sally Jones probability may be consistent with the attribute probabilities, in which case no modification of the Sally Jones prediction is required.

Comment: The baseline is: From the given information it's impossible to tell.